# SVG animation with Velocity.js - $ is not defined

Tags: jquery, animation, svg, velocity.js

I am trying to create a animated logo using SVG and Velocity.js.
When running this project in Chrome it returns the error

```
"$ is not defined"
```

This error appears to be quite common when loading scripts in a wrong order, however I cannot seem to figure out what I am doing wrong.

Running in Safari does not return an error at all, but no animation either.

The HTML document

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Inspades logo</title>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/velocity/1.2.2/velocity.js"></script>

    <style>
        body {
            text-align: center;
            margin: 0px;
            padding: 20vh;
            height: 60vh;
        }

        #logo {
            height: 100%;
        }

        object {
            height: 100%;
        }
    </style>

</head>

<body>

    <div id="logo">
        <object type="image/svg+xml" data="inspades_logo.svg"/>
    </div>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function(){
            console.log("ready!");

            function moonOrbit () {
            $("#moon")
                .velocity({ cx: 15, cy: 285, r: 15 }, { duration: 0 })
                .velocity({ cx: 285, cy: 15, r: 10 }, { duration: 1500, delay: 10 });
            };

            moonOrbit();
         });
    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

The SVG file

```
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 300 300" enable-background="new 0 0 300 300" xml:space="preserve">

    <circle id="moon" cx="15" cy="285" r="15"/>

    <ellipse id="globe" cx="150" cy="150" rx="145" ry="145" fill="rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)" stroke="rgb(0,0,0)" stroke-width="10"/>

</svg>
```

[EDIT]
I tried removing jQuery, since it is no longer necessary for Velocity.js. However this does not solve the error for the undefined variable. Weird, would this mean that there is a bug in the Velocity library?
[/EDIT]

[EDIT]
I edited the code, following Hackerman's advice, however still having no luck on the animation.
[/EDIT]

Hopefully I am not missing something really obvious here, thanks in advance!

Tom

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using `$(document)` and `$("#moon")`, so you have to include jquery in your project; and like you said, your code needs a little bit of refactoring:

#### HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>logo</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/velocity/1.2.2/velocity.js"></script>
</head>
<body style="text-align:center; margin:0px; height:60vh; padding:20vh 20vh">
<div id="logo" style="height:100%">
    <object height:100% type="image/svg+xml" data="logo.svg"/>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
     $(function(){
        console.log("ready!");
        $("#moon").velocity({ opacity: 1, top: "50%" }).velocity({ opacity: 0, top: "-50%" }, { delay: 1000 });
     });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

#### Svg File:

```
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 300 300" enable-background="new 0 0 300 300" xml:space="preserve">   
<circle id="moon" cx="15" cy="285" r="15"/>
<ellipse id="globe" cx="150" cy="150" rx="145" ry="145" fill="rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)" stroke="rgb(0,0,0)" stroke-width="10"/>
</svg>
```

Comment: Oh I thought I could use Velocity.js without jQuery, but you're right "$ not defined"-error is fixed now. However the animation is still not working, apparently the functions do work (console.log's appear), but no animation.

Comment: @TomHemmes the animation is a separate issue :)

Comment: @ajmajmajma Allright, well as they're not related I will do some more research in the velocity documentation and maybe create a new question. Thanks